# Update multiple sudoers file

Tags: sudo

We have multiple Linux servers that authenticate to an Active Directory Domain. For a group in AD, I want to add a list of commands that are allowed to run as root using sudo. I can obviously ssh-in to each computer and update sudoers file -but that will take some time. Also, root login is not allowed. So, password less logins will only work for non-root users.

Is there a quick way to update the sudoers file for each Linux computer at once?  I am thinking of a Perl or Python script with some system administration abilities here.

Update: Thanks veroteq7 and Shane Madden. I had thought about deploying cfengine at one point- but we don't have it running currently. We have decided that using LDAP would be the best solution.  I am getting an error importing the LDIF schema schema.ActiveDirectory for sudo. The error is "parameter is not correct" on line 144.

This is the content from line 144 onwards:

```
dn: CN=sudoRole,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: classSchema
cn: sudoRole
distinguishedName: CN=sudoRole,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
instanceType: 4
possSuperiors: container
possSuperiors: top
subClassOf: top
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.2.1
mayContain: sudoCommand
mayContain: sudoHost
mayContain: sudoOption
mayContain: sudoRunAs
mayContain: sudoRunAsUser
mayContain: sudoRunAsGroup
mayContain: sudoUser
rDNAttID: cn
showInAdvancedViewOnly: FALSE
adminDisplayName: sudoRole
adminDescription: Sudoer Entries
objectClassCategory: 1
lDAPDisplayName: sudoRole
name: sudoRole
schemaIDGUID:: SQn432lnZ0+ukbdh3+gN3w==
systemOnly: FALSE
objectCategory: CN=Class-Schema,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
defaultObjectCategory: CN=sudoRole,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
```

The command that I used is:

```
ldifde -i -f schema.ActiveDirectory -c dc=X dc=DOMAINNAME,dc=LOCAL
```

Update2: I created a new [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/340490/error-importing-sudoers-ldif-schema-to-active-directory). Thanks everybody for suggestions.

Comment: You should probably post the AD Schema-modifying bit as a separate question -- I'm not really up on all the AD-specific stuff that has to be done to modify the LDAP schema & import new objects, but I know we have a lot of MS/AD gurus on here who would pick it up under the [tag:active-directory] & [tag:ldap] tags

Answer (score 17):

Why not scrap `/etc/sudoers` and use AD [(LDAP)](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/readme_ldap.html) as your sudoers store? -- More info [here](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.ldap.man.html).

You're already authenticating against AD, so this is just the next logical step, and gives you a convenient, centralized place to handle authentication *and* authorization.

Comment: For as long as I can remember, we've just done AD/Linux/winbind/PAM and added AD groups to `sudoers` -- I do not know how I've never found this. A much deserved +1.

Comment: @jscott The big downside is a lot of sudo packages don't have LDAP compiled in so you may have to roll your own.  I build sudo from FreeBSD ports, and we already have LDAP dependencies for pam_ldap, so it's no extra headache for me :-)

Answer (score 15):

How about a configuration management tool?  [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/), [CFEngine](http://cfengine.com/), etc?

Answer (score 3):

You can define groups in sudoers... and pull those groups from a central authentication repository... like Active Directory.  I love putting domain admins in my sudoers file.   Saves a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 2):

If you're searching for an API to modify your sudoers file, you can use [Augeas](http://augeas.net) with the Sudoers lens. It integrates nicely with [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), but you could also use it in a script of yours (there's many bindings).

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/340245/29328) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm!! its a pain. 
the other way you can do it with cssh command which will allow you to open multiple windows at a time. if you type something on the tiny window (white blank window), you would notice your typring is propagating through all windows. i would recommand to take a backup of your suoders file and use visudo command to update sudoers.
if anyhting sudoer file dont like, visudo will tell you  to correct the file.

Cheers