# Error importing sudoers ldif schema to Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, ldap, sudo, ldif

As per this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/340147/update-multiple-sudoers-file), we are on the process of migrating our sudoers file to Active Directory. As per the documentation, this requires importing the schema.ActiveDirectory LDIF which comes with the standard installation of sudo. Our Windows Domain is on Windows Server 2003.

I am getting an error importing the LDIF schema to Active Directory. The error is "parameter is not correct" on line 144.

This is the content from line 144 onwards:

```
dn: CN=sudoRole,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: classSchema
cn: sudoRole
distinguishedName: CN=sudoRole,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
instanceType: 4
possSuperiors: container
possSuperiors: top
subClassOf: top
governsID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.2.1
mayContain: sudoCommand
mayContain: sudoHost
mayContain: sudoOption
mayContain: sudoRunAs
mayContain: sudoRunAsUser
mayContain: sudoRunAsGroup
mayContain: sudoUser
rDNAttID: cn
showInAdvancedViewOnly: FALSE
adminDisplayName: sudoRole
adminDescription: Sudoer Entries
objectClassCategory: 1
lDAPDisplayName: sudoRole
name: sudoRole
schemaIDGUID:: SQn432lnZ0+ukbdh3+gN3w==
systemOnly: FALSE
objectCategory: CN=Class-Schema,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
defaultObjectCategory: CN=sudoRole,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X
```

The command that I used is:

```
ldifde -i -f schema.ActiveDirectory -c dc=X dc=DOMAINNAME,dc=LOCAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Add option -z and your ldif will import successfully.